# 2 jquery datepickers: limit date range

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can anyone tell me how i can limited the date range of either picker based on the selection in the other. For example i have a DateFrom and a DateTo picker. how can i ensure that the is always a 5 day gap between the date ranges?

```
            $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'd-M-y',
                defaultDate: null,
                changeMonth: true,
                minDate: 0,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                }
            });
            //jquery date picker configuration
            $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'd-M-y',
                defaultDate: null,
                changeMonth: true,
                minDate: 0,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                }
            });
```

Both my jquery datepicker options look like the above. On the Onclose functions i tried adding '+ 5" but that didn't seem to work. If anyone can help id be appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
```

to this:

```
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", +5, selectedDate );
```

it worked in a similar problem I had